# How to split JSON column

Tags: python, json, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe with JSON column containing long text in this structure:

```
[['A','B','C'],['A','B','D'],['A','B','E']]
```

I need to split it into new three columns with content of `'C'`, `'D'`, and `'E'`. The problem is that part of data are without the third square bracket `['A','B','E']`.

Do you have any idea what to do with this?

Comment: add the expected output

Comment: output should look like this: https://imgur.com/jWoxzuS

Comment: can you add some more data including this condition "part of data are without the third square bracket"

Comment: some of them are like this: [['custom-field2', 'voucher', 'number of voucher'], ['custom-field2', 'voucher', 'note']]   and some of them are like this: [['custom-field2', 'voucher', 'number of voucher'], ['custom-field2', 'voucher', 'note']],['custom-field2', 'voucher', 'language']]

Comment: I would like to create 3 new columns and leave NaN in third column in case of missing value. I am beginner, so I hope it makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[['A','B','C'],['A','B','D'],['A','B','E']], [['X','Y','Z'],['R','S','T']], [['I','J','K'],['L','M','N'],['O','P','Q']]]})
df = pd.DataFrame(df['A'].apply(lambda x: [lst[2] for lst in x]).tolist())
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   0  1     2
0  C  D     E
1  Z  T  None
2  K  N     Q
```

Comment: Great thanks! I forget to mention that I am creating a script that would be automatically generated from csv file on daily basis, so I dont want to manually put column content to the code, but prefer option which automatically connecting the code with already created column like df['column name'] or somethign like this.

Comment: @JanaStará I didn't understood what you are saying

Comment: if there is any other way which doesn't require to put manually ['A','B','C'],['A','B','D'],['A','B','E']], [['X','Y','Z'],['R','S','T']], [['I','J','K'],['L','M','N'],['O','P','Q']] into the code but automatically counts with the content of particular column?

Comment: @JanaStará I just created that as an example. If you already have a dataframe then you can remove firstline and change column name in secondline It will work.